# gnu make hash symbol in the middle of string

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to print out the perforce file version of the make file when it's executed. I'm using the `$Id$` tag, which expands to `$Id: //repository/path/check.make#6 $` or the like and I want to print `//repository/path/check.make#6` to a file (currently using echo). I can't figure out how to get make to take the # as part of the string and not the beginning of a comment. I tried:

```
str1 = $(subst \#,\\\#,'$Id: //repository/path/check.make#6 $')
```

and other variations but I keep getting:

```
 unterminated call to function `subst': missing `)'.  Stop.
```

Comment: I just want to print out the variable with '#' in the middle of it. My current strategy was to attempt to replace '#' with '\#'.

Comment: You have a variable that contains a string that contains a `#`, and you want to print that string, is that right?

Comment: yes, I'm using $Id$ in my perforce file which expands out to something like "$Id: //repository/path/check.make#6 $". I want to print out "//repository/path/check.make#6" from that, so I need the # to be seen as a string character and not the start of a comment.

Comment: yes, I can't have a unescaped literal # in the Makefile and not have it interpreted as a comment. So what I have is a string which contains an unescaped #, and my efforts to use subst to add in the escape character have been unsuccessful thus far.

Comment: I think this needs a bit more background. When I submit a change to the file in perforce the version number changes, so instead of being //repository/path/check.make#6 the new version would be //repository/path/check.make#7. Perforce allows you to reference that information within the script by adding $Id$ to the code, which  gets expanded to "$Id: //repository/path/check.make#6 $" or "$Id: //repository/path/check.make#7 $". Which gives your script the ability to record which version of itself is being run. I want to print out that string, but it contains a # so I can't unless I can escape it.

Comment: Can you tell me why you preferred tripleee's answer over mine?

Comment: I put $Id$ in my code, and the CM tool expands that to something like "$Id: //repository/path/check.make#6 $". So I have that string in my code, but I didn't put it there, get it from an argument or control it's value. From that string I need to extract the middle field and write it to a file. In order to do that, I need to escape the "#" symbol. Even though it's not an ideal solution, I can do the extraction and add the escape character with sed, I couldn't figure any way (hence the question) to add the escape character before the # character with Make commands.

Comment: Yes I understood you correctly then. My solution does exactly what you want without resorting to a second tool on the shell. To get the middle string just do a `$(word 2,$(value PERFORCE_ID))`

Comment: When I do $(word 2,$(value PERFORCE_ID)) I get the message "*** missing separator.  Stop." because it interprets the # in the middle of the string as the start of a comment and therefore it ignores the close parens because they're part of the comment, at least that's my interpretation of why I'm getting that error message. Maybe I'm missing something from your explanation because I don't seem to be able to get this to work if I don't somehow escape that character.

Comment: No, sorry, then you are doing something wrong. When a `#` is inside a variable, it is just a normal character which is *not interpreted*. Only when it gets into a context where the make parser is interpreting it again, it will be seen as a comment start, .e.g. in an `eval` call.

Comment: Maybe it's because we have an older version (3.8) of make on the system? Other than that, I don't know exactly what I'd be doing wrong as I copied your code directly and got that error message,

Comment: Ok, ´3.80´ is really old - 18 years! Which system is this, that forces you to use such an outdated tool?

Comment: I couldn't even get my hand on a running version 3.80. In 3.81 however, the method works as expected. 3.80 seems to have some bugs in the `eval` method - an update to 3.81 is strongly recommendable.

Comment: Can you either accept or remove the question? Or at least write an explanation - as it stands, my solution is correct and by far the simplest save for the bug in 3.80.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't have an unescaped literal `#` in a `make` assignment and not have it be interpreted as a comment character. But as a hack, you can have the shell extract this token from the current `Makefile`.

```
# $Id: //repository/path/check.make#6 $
str1 := $(shell sed '/[$$]Id[$$:]/!d;s/^\# [$$]Id: \(.*\) [$$].*/\1/' Makefile)
```

The `sed` script looks for the `$Id$` or `$Id:` token *in the Makefile itself* by way of a regex which doesn't match itself; the doubled dollar sign is how you put a literal dollar sign in a Makefile. It extracts the contents of the field, and `make` assigns the output to `str1`. Because there is no literal `#` in the code which assigns the variable, no further escaping is necessary.

Demo: https://ideone.com/hWjnCp

This requires GNU Make, but that's apparently what you are using already. (Please tag such questions explicitly as [gnu-make](/questions/tagged/gnu-make).)

Comment: Note that handling of `#` in GNU make was adjusted (fixed) in GNU make 4.3 so you no longer need backslashes.  For portability it's best to declare a variable as in my example above: `HASH = \#` then use that in your `shell` function.

Comment: str1 = $(shell sed -n '/[$$]Id:/s/.* \(\/\/.*\)\#\([0-9]*\) .*/\1\\\#\2/gp' $(firstword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)) )
 was what I ended up with (excuse my poor formatting skillls)

Comment: You can use an alternate separator 's%regex%subst%p` so you don't have to escape the literal slashes. I don't see why you would need a `g` flag; surely, you don't have more than one of these identifiers on the same line?

Comment: "_You can't have an unescaped literal #_" well, in multi-line defines you can :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I didn't get you correctly but the following works for an outside actor replacing `$Id$` without escaping:

```
define PERFORCE_ID
$Id$
endef

PERFORCE_ID := $(word 2,$(value PERFORCE_ID))
$(info $(PERFORCE_ID))
```

As a test, I simply put in the text substitution from Perforce myself:

```
define PERFORCE_ID
$Id: //repository/path/check.make#6 $                                                                                                                                                      
endef

PERFORCE_ID := $(word 2,$(value PERFORCE_ID))                                                                                                                                              
$(info Perforce id is: $(PERFORCE_ID))
```

Output:

```
Perforce id is: //repository/path/check.make#6
```

Answer (score 1):

As with GNU Make 4.4.1 the above solutions does not satisfy me, because I use `automake` to generate `Makefile`s based on custom `*.am` templates.

`automake` threw an error:

> error: comment following trailing backslash:

caused by this assignment:

```
HASH := \#
```

So I solved it in custom `*.am` file with `define`-command:

```
define HASH
#
endef

str1 = $(subst \$(HASH),\\\$(HASH),"$Id: //repository/path/check.make$(HASH)6 $")

all:
     $(shell echo '$(str1)' >&2)
```

Comment: I don't think you're correct.  I just tried the example in my answer below `HASH := \#` and it works fine with GNU Make 4.4.1, with no errors.  I'm not aware of any error message close to what you suggest above in GNU Make code.  Please show the exact thing you tried and the exact error message you got (cut and paste).

Comment: You are right. My case also makes use of `autoconf` and custom `*.am` files. That is where the error ` error: comment following trailing backslash:` occurs.

Comment: Good note about automake files.  That wasn't what the original question was about but others might find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you provided a full example of what you want.  I don't really understand why you're trying to `subst` a hash with a backslash hash.  If you showed us a full example, including how you get the string and also what you want to do with the variable `ar1`, we could actually give you advice.

But, the way to use hashes in GNU make is to put them into a variable:

```
HASH := \#

$(info HASH = $(HASH))
```

That's all I can say without more info.

**ETA**

Yes, I'm very familiar with keyword expansion... it originated with SCCS/RCS back in the day :).

I see, you  mean, you want to put the `$Id$` *into your makefile*, then when your makefile is checked out the value will be replaced.  That wasn't clear to me.

I'm sorry to say that what you want to do is close to impossible.  The problem is that you can't escape the value in the makefile because you're not writing the value into the makefile, Perforce is.  And Perforce is not escaping it.

You have only two options that I can see:

First, don't try to put this into a make variable.  There are many ways to do this, depending on what you really want.  One way is to create a header file that contains `const char* foo = "$Id$";` and let that be replaced.  If you really want the ID of the makefile, but you only need it within a certain recipe, you can put it directly into that recipe:

```
myrecipe: ; echo '$$Id$$'
```

(I'm not actually sure the `$$` trick here will work, it depends on how Perforce replaces things... if it doesn't you can use `echo '$Id$x'` you'll lose the dollar signs but keep the rest).

The only other option is to upgrade your version of GNU make to the latest (4.3).  In that release, some broken handling of hash characters in the `$(shell ...)` function was fixed, which means you can use:

```
var1 := $(shell echo '$$Id$$')
```

and it will work (same caveats, and solutions, for `$$` here as above).

Comment: Perforce has a feature (rcs tagging) where you put keywords in your code and it expands them, so if I put $Id$ in my file and submit it the file will contain "$Id: //repository/check.make#6 $" instead of $Id$. I want to set a var to $Id$ (which will expand to //repository/check.make#6) and print the file version executed when the code runs. When I go to print out the version (//repository/check.make#6) it drops the #6 because of the comment character. Escaping the # would work, but I can't figure out the syntax to change "//repository/check.make#6" to "//repository/check.make\#6".

Comment: Is the literal `#` in multi-line defines (see my solution) a bug or a feature? Will it go away some day?

Comment: I mistakenly downvoted your solution because I confused my '*.am' files with pure 'Makefile'. Your solution does not work with 'automake' though.

Comment: The question wasn't asking about automake files, however.  If it had been then definitely we would have provided a different answer.